# Unit testing a Winforms event driven architecture

Tags: .net, winforms, unit-testing, nunit

What approach should I take (if it's even possible) to unit test a standard event driven Winforms app where display and logic are mixed together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a UI Automation testing framework, unless you want to rework your UI to decouple the display and logic.

Some examples include products like [TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete).

Visual Studio 2010 is [going to add some functionality](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T83M) for this exact scenario, as well.

Comment: To my experience, its better to separate display and logic. Those GUI Robot applications may only be helpful if you have a separate testing department which is really willing to use them because they save them some effort.

Comment: I agree, completely. However, the OP asked how to test an app that explicitly has display + logic mixed...